# mysql boolean search weighting columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in mysql which have full text search enabled:

title (title, url), headings (headings, url), and content (content, url).

My question is this: I wanted weight the url column more than the title, title column more than the headings, and the headings more than the content. Could I do this with boolean searches where each term is required, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE MATCH (title)
AGAINST('+search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATCH ...AGAINST` returns a number, and MySQL remembers the result of the where clause, so if you have 3 separate FT-indexes on 1 table, you could just do a:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
  MATCH (title)    AGAINST('search')
  OR MATCH (headings) AGAINST('search')
  OR MATCH (content) AGAINST('search')
ORDER BY 
  (MATCH (title) AGAINST('search') * 3) + 
  (MATCH (headings) AGAINST('search') * 2) +
  MATCH (content) AGAINST('content') DESC
```

Or whatever the weights may need to be.

Alternatively, in Boolean mode, same table, you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
  MATCH (title)    AGAINST('>>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  OR MATCH (headings) AGAINST('>>search' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
  OR MATCH (content) AGAINST('>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY 
  MATCH (title) AGAINST('>>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE) + 
  MATCH (headings) AGAINST('>>search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) +
  MATCH (content) AGAINST('>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

For searches where the searchterm is required, same trick:

```
 MATCH (title) AGAINST('+>>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If you have 3 separate tables, you'll have to store the weight somewhere, either in some JOIN, or by separate queries (however you do it now):

```
SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST('+>>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE) as weight
FROM title
WHERE     MATCH (title) AGAINST('+>>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)

SELECT *, MATCH (headings) AGAINST('+>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE) as weight
FROM headings
WHERE     MATCH (headings) AGAINST('+>>search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)

SELECT *, MATCH (content) AGAINST('+search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE) as weight
FROM content
WHERE     MATCH (content) AGAINST('+search'   IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: would using union be a better way for the 3rd case (having 3 seperate tables)

Comment: Probably, depends on what you're doing & how the join is done. Most likely you'll want to use the ORDER BY clause from the second example in that case.

Comment: `>>>` is invalid syntax; https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qgfA6gKMxnHt2ETmMZKCSQ/0

Comment: Indeed, `>>` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Keep in mind this answer was for MySQL 5.0 around that time. It's ancient.